# how to unittest a java method when data is created inside the constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a class which exposes a set of apis as below

```
class MyDataProcessor{    
    private int M;
    private double[] data;

    public MyDataProcessor(int N,int M){
        this.M = M;
        this.data = new double[M];
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
            int randomX = //get a random value
            double v = processValue(randomX);
            this.data[i] = v;
        }
    private static double processValue(int randomX){
         //do some work on randomX and return a double value
    }

    private double mean(double[] a){
        double meanValue = //find mean of a
        return meanValue;
    }

    private double stddev(double[] a){
        double stdDevValue = //find stddev of a
        return stdDevValue;
    }

    public double lowerBoundConf(){
        double mean = mean(this.data);
        double sd = stddev(this.data);
        double lb = mean + (1.96*stddev)/Math.sqrt(this.M);
        return lb;
    }
}
```

Here,I have to unit test the method `lowerBoundConf`.I cannot provide a double[] array to this method(that would have made it simple).The array has to come from inside the constructor.I cannot figure out how I can write tests for this.Can someone help?

Comment: You could add a second (package-private) constructor that takes the array as a parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately,it is forbidden to add any public methods or constructors

Comment: @ damon :  One of(main) the objective of unit tests is to make code testable. You should prefer making the code testable. Alternatives are not pretty. Use reflection to change created object. Or mock framework like jmockit..

Comment: On second thoughts ;p if the unit test is in the same package as the class under test, then I can make a package-private constructor as @Thilo suggested..It wont work if unit tests are in a different packeage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing any functionality of your class you need to access the data array. Make the field package protected final to test the methods against the data values.

But why test calculations on unknown random data? This is useless (homework?) and also only random result.

Comment: not testing on unknown random data..The random data comes from running an experiment mutliple times.. I need to test against a fixed data array whose mean/stddev are known sothat I can know if the method impl is correct..I think a friendly constructor taking a data array is the only way . ps:..it's not a homework :)

Comment: @damon that context makes the question more clear! Yes, you need a package protected constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Testing methods that deal with random is always hard.

But you can still test the whole class. You have expect something from that method when you give here specific parameters and thats how your tests should look like.

When you don't know the concrete values that are returned test some information around that like min/max.

An other alternativ would be using Mock frameworks like Mockito which is pretty hard inyour case because all but one methods are private